# How to insert separator (comma) in a character?

Tags: r, string, paste, cat

How can I change `@ManuelaSchwesig@sigmargabriel@nahles` into `@ManuelaSchwesig`, `@sigmargabriel`, `@nahles` using R?

Comment: See `?strsplit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could try with a regex lookaround by splitting at the junction of a lower case letter and the @ character to create a `vector` of strings.  Here, the pattern for `strsplit` is a positive regex lookbehind (`(?<=[a-z])`) followed by a positive regex lookahead (`(?=@)`).  In the string, there are two instances where it matches i.e. between `g` and `@` (Schweig@sigma) and `l` and `@` in (gabriel@nahles) and splits between these characters

```
strsplit(str1, "(?<=[a-z])(?=@)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "@ManuelaSchwesig" "@sigmargabriel"   "@nahles"
```

---

If we need to keep it as a single string and the objective is to insert a `,`

```
gsub("([a-z])@", "\\1,@", str1)
#[1] "@ManuelaSchwesig,@sigmargabriel,@nahles"
```

#### data

```
str1 <-  "@ManuelaSchwesig@sigmargabriel@nahles"
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  Thanks, I updated with some explanation.  Hope it helps.  For more regex info, please look into [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)